# specify class AFTER pseudo element in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is there anyway to specify a `class` after a pseudo element? For example, I want to find the `:last-child`of the parent - and if that child has x-class, style accordingly. With SCSS, this would be relatively easier, but the project I'm working on doesn't use SASS.

Any ideas?

Here's what I was trying to do...which is obvs wrong:

```
form .entry-form-wrap :last-child.nested-tmpl-inner
```

HTML is too complex to post, but I've included a general block of code to give you an idea of the flow:

```
<form>
    <div class="entry-form-wrap">
        <div class="some-class" />
        <div class="some-class" />
        <div class="some-class nested-tmpl-inner" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You should post some relevant html as well.

Comment: You cannot specify a class selector after a pseudo-element, since pseudo-elements cannot have classes, but you *can* specify a class selector after a pseudo-class (which is what `:last-child` is), because simple selectors can be arranged in any order in a chain (with the exception of type/universal always appearing first). The selector that you have is valid, but a selector like `::after.class` would be invalid. This is why the distinction between pseudo-elements and pseudo-classes is so important.

Comment: Agh - nice! Makes complete sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not obvs wrong. You **can** specify a class right after the pseudo, like `:pseudo.class`.

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fYy4T/

Comment: Interesting...wasn't working for me. Let me see if I have an error somewhere.

Comment: My problem wasn't the CSS persay, it was that I have hidden div's below the class I'm trying to target. So `:last-child` is not getting triggered...